# How to kill htop if I can't use F10?

Tags: gnome, 15.04, gnome-terminal, htop

I use `htop` in a terminal but I can't close it with <kbd>F10</kbd>. <kbd>F10</kbd> seems to just open a program's *File* dialog. Is there a way to disable it so I can close `htop` normally?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You always can have the interupt signal keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

Basically <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> sends the SIGINT (interrupt) signal, ; by default, this causes the process to terminate.

Just like `top`, `htop` can be quit by pressing <kbd>Q</kbd>.

> SIGINT
>
> The SIGINT signal is sent to a process by its controlling
> terminal when a user wishes to interrupt the process. This is
> typically initiated by pressing Control-C, but on some systems, the
> "delete" character or "break" key can be used

Comment: If you exit `htop` with Ctrl+C (SIGINT), `htop` will exit with a failure status (status code 1) and will not save any settings (like the sort column, etc.).

Answer (score 49):

**TL;DR** The standard way to quit `htop` is <kbd>F10</kbd> **or** <kbd>q</kbd>.

---

Therefore if you can't use <kbd>F10</kbd>,  use <kbd>q</kbd> (lowercase).

[image]

Comment: Note that this is a lower-case `q`, not a capital one.

Answer (score 19):

If you are using gnome-terminal, yes, you can disable that the F10 key opens the menu:

Open gnome-terminal's menu with F10 or with the mouse and go to *Preferences*. In the *General* section and disable the *Enable the menu accelerator key (F10 by default)* option.

[image]

Comment: This is not a gnome-terminal issue. F10 seems to do the same annoying thing for any program and there doesn't even seem to be a shortcut registered in the Gnome shortcut settings :(

Comment: Solution worked for me. As of Ubuntu 18.04 setting was in Edit > Preferences > General

Answer (score 2):

All sorts of other options apart from q.

- Open another terminal and kill it from there.
- Kill it from the System Monitor task list.
- Close the terminal window.

These assume a desktop environment.

Also for servers...

- Ctrl-Alt-F1 (or F6/F7) and log in again to kill.
- Connect again (Telnet/SSH) and kill.

And finally - it is open source, patch it.

Answer (score 1):

If you're interested in making F10 (and other shortucts) available in general to terminal applications and you're using XFCE terminal, go to
 Edit -> Preferences -> Advanced -> Shortcuts
and check the appropriate boxes to disable the keys. I have them all checked so that Emacs (m-f) and htop (F10) will work.