# Ubuntu 18.04 Terminal F10 function key conflict with htop

Tags: gnome-terminal, 18.04

In htop <kbd>F10</kbd> is used to exit but it conflicts with Terminal function to show menu instead.

How can we unbind <kbd>F10</kbd> in terminal?

Answer (score 60, accepted):

1. Edit -> Preferences -> General:
2. Uncheck *"Enable the accelerator key (F10 by default)"*

[image: Terminal settings]

If this is the only conflict you could [also use <kbd>Ctrl + c</kbd> or just <kbd>q</kbd> to quit `htop`](https://askubuntu.com/a/643090/349837).

Comment: Seems baffling that this isn't under Shortcuts...

Comment: Seems even baffling that this is a default setting for a linux terminal. Nuts.

Comment: you saved my day!

Comment: Finally I can start using Midnight Commander properly.

Comment: I hate this default, and I am among the first to set it up on every install - ubuntu 18.04 and 20.04

Comment: Thank you very much!